# How override root.tsx Meta tags in another files in remix?

Tags: metadata, remix.run

Let's in root i have this meta function

```js
export const meta: MetaFunction = () => {
   return [{ title:"my remix"}, 
    {
      property: "og:title",
      content: "my og",
    },  
    {
      property: "og:url",
      content: "https://myurl.com",
    },
    {
      name: "description",
      content:"my description",
    }]
}
```

now I have routes like

- /my => my._index.ts
- /my/pages/profile => my.pages.profile.tsx
- /my/pay/subscription=>my.pay.subscription.tsx

i want override og:title in profile and just title in subscription for meta tags and want same meta tags defined in root  for my._index.ts

Update:
I can achieve this using merge meta helper in remix another way is write meta tags each n every page by duplicating some tags  from parent which approach is better according to you?

Comment: There is a section in the documentation that talks about this. https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/meta#gotchas-with-meta-and-nested-routes